# Querying SQL Server on remote host arises a Character Set Problem

Tags: sql-server

When calling to SQL SERVER on remote hosting with query below a problem occurs:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '..ş'
```

Table Names, having Local Culture Alphabet do not return in query, although they are in schema. For example, tables with Turkish Chars like 'ı' 'ş' not seen in query result...

Comment: Use `TABLE_NAME = N'..ş'` to specify that the string is Unicode.

Comment: one more point, this has to be done with every query, is there a global way when querying to this kind of servers with numerous queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set collation when creating or altering:

```
use master
ALTER DATABASE YourDataBase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE    
ALTER DATABASE YourDataBase COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS
ALTER DATABASE YourDataBase SET MULTI_USER
```

this time no need to use N' in each query.